# unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, maven, spring-tool-suite

Me baje un proyecto en: https://start.spring.io/ 
A importarlo en mi eclipse me da error en mi pom.ml

```
POM.XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

El error que me dice por consola es este:

```
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for com.nocompila:spring-boot-rules:0.1.0
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.nocompila:spring-boot-rules:0.1.0: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.3.RELEASE from https://nexus.alm.gsnetcloud.corp/repository/maven-central/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven-central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.3.RELEASE from/to maven-central (https://nexus.alm.gsnetcloud.corp/repository/maven-central/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 10, column 13
 for project com.nocompila:spring-boot-rules:0.1.0 at D:\microServicios\EjemplosMicroServicios\demo\demo\pom.xml
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$5.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$5.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.execute(ProjectRegistryManager.java:967)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.readProjectWithDependencies(ProjectRegistryManager.java:811)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.create(ProjectRegistryManager.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.MavenProjectManager.create(MavenProjectManager.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.actions.SelectionUtil.getMavenProject(SelectionUtil.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.editor.pom.MavenPomEditor.readMavenProject(MavenPomEditor.java:742)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.editor.pom.MavenPomEditor$5.run(MavenPomEditor.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for com.nocompila:spring-boot-rules:0.1.0
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.nocompila:spring-boot-rules:0.1.0: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.3.RELEASE from https://nexus.alm.gsnetcloud.corp/repository/maven-central/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven-central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.3.RELEASE from/to maven-central (https://nexus.alm.gsnetcloud.corp/repository/maven-central/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 10, column 13

    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelProblemCollector.newModelBuildingException(DefaultModelProblemCollector.java:197)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1029)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:800)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:329)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:161)
    ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 2):

> from https://nexus.alm.gsnetcloud.corp/repository/maven-central/

y

> PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 10, column 13

En Java "PKIX path building failed" siempre te dice que ha intentado contactar con una URL HTTPS pero que no ha podido validar su certificado.

Cuando se establece una conexión HTTPS, el servidor remoto envía la clave pública de su certificado para que verifiques que te estás conectando con él. Aparte de otras cosas (que no esté caducado, que el certificado tenga el nombre del servidor, etc.), te envía una serie de CAs que autentifican el certificado. Si tu programa se fía del certificado, la conexión se establece.

Y la parte divertida es la de que el programa "se fíe"; para eso lo normal<sup>1</sup> es que tu programa tenga su propia lista de los certificados (de servidores y CA) de los que se fía, si el certificado que le llega está en la lista o está firmado por una de las CAs de las que se fía.

Los pasos para importar el certificado son algo largos y además hay muchas opciones; te indico aquí los pasos generales:

- Descargar los certificados como .der. Puedes usar el navegador (vas a la URL indicada, haces click en los detalles de certificado y exportas el certificado que prefieras<sup>2</sup>), o algún programa como open_ssl.
- Añadir el certificado a un keystore, usando la herramienta keytool de java. Puedes añadirlo al keystore del sistema ([JDK_HOME]/jre/lib/security/cacerts) o crear tu propio keystore.
- Si has creado tu propio keystore, pasárselo al programa; lo habitual es definiendo (-D[nombreVariable]=[valor]) las variables de entorno *javax.net.ssl.trustStore* y *javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword*.

---

<sup>1</sup>Los programas interactivos a veces pueden pedir confirmación al usuario (p.ej. navegadores), pero Maven es completamente anti-interactivo.

<sup>2</sup>Puedes poner en tu lista de certificados de confianza solo el certificado de ese servidor, o una de sus CAs.

Comment: ¿Cómo se le pasan las variables para especificar el keystore local?

Comment: @EnriMR Como propiedades del sistema al invocar java: *java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=[ruta] -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=[contraseña]*